# OpenStack cinder api - Malformed request url

Tags: openstack, cinder

I Have an issue using Cinder API v3, ended getting below error

```
http://openstack_api:8776/v3/project_ID/volumes/detail


{
    "badRequest": {
        "code": 400,
        "message": "Malformed request url"
    }
}
```

Note that I was able to query Keystone to get token and used the token in Nova and it returns a result, unlike cinder.

Tried to debug from openstack client and result returned successfully using the same query I'm using in api, the only difference is that in openstack stack client the token in header is using {SHA256} and mine that extracted from keynote does not.

any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you do to get this error?

Comment: I was using wrong tenant ID, check my answer

Answer (score 3):

Ok, the issue resolved, after running a debug from openstack client using -vvv so this trick leads to what API call performed to list volumes

the issue was that token generated was from admin project, and I put in volumes API another project, the error message was misleading ! changed api call to admin project and it was successfull

to list all volumes for all tenants use
http://:8776/v3//volumes/detail?**all_tenants=True**